# ¿Cómo imprimir solo los últimos 10 registros de un JSON?

Tags: jquery, json

Tengo este código para recorrer un JSON e imprimirlo en un select, que puedo hacer para que solo recorra los últimos 10 registros del JSON. No puedo modificar consulta SQL donde se genera el JSON por ello lo que pretendo es trabajar solo con el JSON.

```
$.getJSON('/storage/mh.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        $("#dts").append('<option name="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
    }); // close each()
}); // close getJSON()
```

Si creen que falta información pidanla.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de JSON que recibas? Es para saber si lo que recibes en la variable `data` es un array o un objeto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes invertir el json con la función **reverse()**.

```
varJson.reverse()
```

Si te funciona esto, solo faltaría que limites tu resultado a 10, pero no olvides que la función each() inicia en 0, entonces:

```
return index<9;
```

Revisa este ejemplo: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Capriatto/8znro6be/5/#&togetherjs=2akapdqUxO)

Answer (score 0):

> Este código devuelve los ultimos 2 elementos, espero te sirva.

```
var arr = [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "A"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "B"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "C"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "D"
    },
    {
        "id": "n",
        "name": "X"
    }
]
Array.prototype.last = function(n){
  return this.slice(-n)
};

console.log( arr.last(2) )
```

Comment: Si se hace de esta manera, hay que tener en cuenta que se está modificando el objeto global `Array`. También hay que tener en cuenta  que el array que pasemos a la función `splice` quedará modificado, por lo que si después necesitamos acceder a alguna otra posición del array habremos perdido esos datos. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice

Comment: Buena observacion, entonces, para evitar "romper" el array trabajariamos con una copia, verdad? Y si quiero evitar modificar el objeto global Array se podria hacer algo parecido? Pregunto porque soy bastante novato y me parecieron interesantes tus observaciones, muchas gracias

Comment: Aunque es verdad que se puede hacer una copia para no perder datos, lo ideal es utilizar `splice` solamente si nuestra intención es borrar datos y que el array quede verdaderamente modificado. Si solo necesitamos acceder a las últimas posiciones, se puede llegar a ellas sin tener que modificar ni duplicar el array original. Para lo del objeto `Array` no hay necesidad de añadir la función `last` a su prototipo. Se puede utilizar `splice` directamente, porque lo único que hace last es hacer negativo el índice. Si aún así se quiere que esté en una función se puede definir así: (Continúo abajo)

Comment: `function last(arr, n) { return arr.splice(-n); }` Y después se llamaría así: `last(arr, 2);`

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que recibes en `data` es un objeto de pares clave-valor, puedes utilizar la función `Object.keys()`. Esta función te devuelve un array con las clave de un objeto. Una vez tenga las claves, empiezas a iterar desde la longitud del array menos 10, e iteras hasta el final del array.

```
var keys = Object.keys(data);

var inicio = keys.length - 10;

for (var i = inicio; i < keys.length; i++) {
   var key = keys[i];
   var value = data[key];
   $("#dts").append('<option name="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
}
```

Si lo que recibes en `data` es un array, es la misma estrategia pero no necesitas llamar a `Object.keys()`:

```
var inicio = data.length - 10;

for (var key = inicio; key < data.length; key++) {
   var value = data[key];
   $("#dts").append('<option name="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
}
```

En este caso se entiende que la clave es la posición del array.

Por último, que no se te olvide controlar la longitud del array por si tiene menos de 10 elementos, ya que al restarle 10 te daría negativo y el programa no tendría el comportamiento esperado

Más información:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys